# New Attribute Group not available for selection in Channel Address Order screen

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I am trying to set a specific data extension as the 1st listing/default on the Channel Address Order screen in Contact Builder. Have created an Attribute Group and linked said data extension. The Attribute Group does not show up as an option to select an address from when I click Edit -> Add Address (only options I see are for "Email Address" and for synchronized data extensions (Users & Contacts). I see documentation and posts suggesting this is how to add new entries. Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: Have yous set a subscriber relationship on the data extension?

Comment: Yes, that is set and it does show as sendable.

Comment: @Toye Begbaaji create poplutions in Data Designer not  Attribute Group then check   its showing Email filed

Comment: Will give that a go and report back!

Answer (score 1):

Only email address attributes in Populations are available for selection as a Channel Address Order.

Comment: if you create Populations with link data extension   in Data Designer  then its showing data extension  Email field in Channel Address Order

Comment: @Toye Begbaaji, does this answer your question?